Is the language $L = \{wuw^R: w, u \in \{a,b\}^* \wedge |w| = |u|\}$ context-free?
It appears to me that the language $L = \{wuw^R: w, u \in \{a,b\}^* \wedge |w| = |u|\}$ is not context-free because of the restriction on $|w| = |u|$. I've tried to come up with a CFG for it, but I cannot guarantee that the size of $w$ and $u$ will be equal. Am I missing something? Any insight is appreciated.

Have you tried the pumping lemma, with, for example, $ba^nb^{n+1}a^nb$?

@Nathaniel I've tried with $a^mb^ma^2mb^ma^m$. It indicates that it is not context free, but I'm not sure I trust my answer

Sorry that should be $a^mb^ma^{2m}b^ma^m$

(Your try is more involved than Nathaniels - try to think even more simple.)
